# Read JSON file (arrays of objects) and create beans for each JSON object

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a use case where I have to initialize list of beans but the configuration for beans is stored in a JSON file (eventually externalised). These beans eventually will be fed to the builder that is responsible for using them.

I am thinking:

1. Create a Spring component that reads JSON file (not sure if I can curl from an external URL or should I store the JSON file within app context). How would I initialize array of beans on the fly?
2. Create another (/use same?) component that feeds to the builder. If that builder is also instantiated using Bean annotation taking in arrays of bean config Java class, how can I control the order of execution that the array of beans gets initialized first and then the builder bean gets instantiated?